# TensorFlow strings: what they are and how to work with them

Tags: python, string, numpy, tensorflow, tfrecord

When I read file with `tf.read_file` I get something with type `tf.string`. Documentation says only that it is "Variable length byte arrays. Each element of a Tensor is a byte array." (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/resources/dims_types.html). I have no idea how to interpret this.

I can do nothing with this type. In usual python you can get elements by index like `my_string[:4]`, but when I run following code I get an error.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.constant("This is string")
y = x[:4]


init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
result = sess.run(y)
print result
```

It says

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 621, in assert_has_rank
    raise ValueError("Shape %s must have rank %d" % (self, rank))
ValueError: Shape () must have rank 1
```

Also I cannot convert my string to `tf.float32` tensor. It is `.flo` file and it has magic header "PIEH". This numpy code successfuly convert such header into number (see example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/28016469/4744283) but I can't do that with tensorflow. I tried `tf.string_to_number(string, out_type=tf.float32)` but it says

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: StringToNumberOp could not correctly convert string: PIEH
```

So, what string is? What it's shape is? How can I at least get part of the string? I suppose that if I can get part of it I can just skip "PIEH" part.

**UPD**: I forgot to say that `tf.slice(string, [0], [4])` also doesn't work with same error.

Comment: BTW, you can get a list of ops that accept tf.string data types using this script: https://gist.github.com/yaroslavvb/16bb81fcfb0932169087add47ecb8c3a

Comment: Thanks for answers!


Is this script for particular version of TF? It doesn't work for at least 0.9. Will try to update to 0.10.

Comment: No, it doesn't work also for 0.10
```$ python list_ops.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "list_ops.py", line 23, in <module>
    if arg.type == tf.string:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py", line 244, in __eq__
    and self._type_enum == as_dtype(other).as_datatype_enum)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py", line 532, in as_dtype
    if key == type_value:
TypeError: data type not understood
```

Can you help me to fix it?

Comment: Seems like I have fixed it :)
23 line must be `if arg.type == tf.string.as_datatype_enum:`

Comment: I suspect you are using 0.9 version or older of TensorFlow, there's no such line in dtypes.py and it hasn't been touched since 0.10 release

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Unlike Python, where a string can be treated as a list of characters for the purposes of slicing and such, TensorFlow's `tf.string`s are indivisible values. For instance, `x` below is a `Tensor` with shape `(2,)` whose each element is a variable length string.

```
x = tf.constant(["This is a string", "This is another string"])
```

However, to achieve what you want, TensorFlow provides the `tf.decode_raw` operator. It takes a `tf.string` tensor as input, but can decode the string into any other primitive data type. For instance, to interpret the string as a tensor of characters, you can do the following :

```
x = tf.constant("This is string")
x = tf.decode_raw(x, tf.uint8)
y = x[:4]
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
print(y.eval())
# prints [ 84 104 105 115]
```

Comment: Thanks. 
So, they are scalars or something else?

Comment: They are native string type. You can break it into characters (length 1 strings) using `tf.string_split(s, delimiter="")` in latest version

Comment: `print("".join(map(chr, y.eval())))` is more likely what you want