# How to properly read .exr file and save it to .flo?

Tags: python, tensor, python-imageio

[image]Firstly, I want to explain step by step what I am trying to do:

1. I have game motion vectors stored in .exr file (have no information about pixel format, likely float32), however I am provided with function that decodes velocity.
2. I want to save them to .flo format, and then I use flowiz to check if they are saved correctly
   Current result can be seen in image I provided. The flow is saved in 1/4th of image and duplicated (I am also sure that this flow is correct, but for some reason scaled and duplicated).

Here is my code to read .exr:
iio -imageiov3

```
def read_exr_np(path):
    return np.array(iio.imread(str(path),index=0)[..., :3]).transpose((2,0,1))
```

then I use this code to convert function:

```
def generate_flow_from_exr(exr_path):
    flow_exr=read_exr_np(exr_path)
    flow  = decode_velocity(flow_exr,[1440,2560])
    write_flow(flow,2560,1440,save_path+str(i-1)+".flo")
    os.system("python -m flowiz "+save_path+str(i-1)+".flo")
```

Write function:

```
def write_flow(tensor, width, height, filename):
    f = open(filename, 'wb')
    magic = np.array([202021.25], dtype=np.float32)
    w = np.array([width], dtype=np.int32)
    h = np.array([height], dtype=np.int32)
    magic.tofile(f)
    w.tofile(f)
    h.tofile(f)
    flow = np.asarray(tensor).astype('float32')
    flow.tofile(f)
    f.close()
```

I tried various changes in way of reading image, as I expect that's what causes the issue. Tried to use opencv to read .exr :

```
im2=cv2.imread(path,  cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR | cv2.IMREAD_ANYDEPTH).transpose(2,0,1)
#also tried this:
im2=cv2.imread(path,-1)
```

but they both return some corrupted data, the final flow is totally random.
Also read this:
[reading middlebury 'flow' files with python (bytes array & numpy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28013200/reading-middlebury-flow-files-with-python-bytes-array-numpy)
And That's the format I want to write, however I cannot read exr in a way they provided, as its not saved such way.

EDIT1:
Here is a link to example .exr files:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1sKRkPdNR-B27bPOaph09kwEQaw-1_w_o?usp=sharing

Comment: Maybe you can share your EXR file via Google Drive, or Dropbox.

Comment: @MarkSetchell just posted the link

Comment: Your files look like trains to me, rather than motion vectors.